# I am trying to convert SAS code to R, but I am continuously getting an error "Error: unexpected '}' in " }"

Tags: r, sas, data-analysis

This is the sas code to be converted

```
data dataset; 

if anl01="Y" or anl02="Y" then anl="Y";

if ser="" then do;

  if con="Y" or disab="Y" or dth="Y" or hosp="Y" or life="Y" or mie="Y" then ser="Y";

 else ser="N";

end;

run;
```

I have written R code like this using if condition, not sure if this works but before that I am getting an error regarding flower brackets

```
dataframe<-(if ( is.na(dataframe$SER) && cong=="Y" | disab=="Y" | 

dth=="Y" | hosp=="Y" | 

life=="Y" | mie=="Y"){

  dataframe$ser="Y"

  } else {

    dataframe$ser="N"

  })
```

Comment: Can you give reproducible example of your adarR dataframe?

Comment: In general in if conditions in R it is not = instead it is ==

Answer (score 0):

Here you go mate

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(888)
anl01<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
anl02<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
con<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
disab<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
dth<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
hosp<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
life<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
mie<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("Y", "N"))
ser<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=0.6),labels=c("", "N"))
Have<-data.frame(anl01,anl02,con,disab,dth,hosp,mie,ser)

Want <-Have %>%
  mutate(anl=ifelse(anl01=='Y'| anl02=='Y', 'Y','N'),
         ser=ifelse(ser=='' & (con=='Y' | disab=='Y'| dth=='Y' | hosp=='Y' | life=='Y' | mie=='Y'), 'Y', 'N'))
```